# Write a lambda function to compute the equation and apply it to each element of the 3x3 matrix using a while loop

Tags: python, lambda, while-loop, iteration

The equation is pow(x,2) - 2*x + 3,  while the 3x3 matrix is [1,2,3];[5,6,7];[4,1,6].

Would I start off with the equation using 'y=lambda x: pow(x,2)-2*x + 3, where x is the matrix? I am unsure how to create while loop where the equation is applied to each element

The lambda function works fine on its own, but I am not sure how I apply it to one element at a time.

Comment: "lambda functions" in Python are no different from ordinary functions except that they can be written on one line in an assignment context.  What you want is NumPy.

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop ? That seems like the least efficient construct for that type of work. Is this a homework ?  Also, why a lamba instead of a function ? Setting a lambda to a variable is already considered bad practice and may eventually be prohibited in Python.

Comment: I need to use a while loop because that is what is asked to do in the homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually many ways of doing this but I will only write down a few. I'm assuming your matrix is a nested list.
As it was pointed out by someone before the most readable (maybe best) way would be to use nested list comprehension:

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [4, 1, 6]]
[[ele**2 - 2*ele + 3 for ele in row] for row in mat]
>> [[2, 3, 6], [18, 27, 38], [11, 2, 27]]
```

If you you want/have to use a lambda there's no need to store it inside a variable. Instead you can just use it inside the nested list comprehension or inside the inbuilt `map()`-function. Using nested list comprehension:

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [4, 1, 6]]
[[(lambda x: x**2 - 2*x + 3)(ele) for ele in row] for row in mat]
>> [[2, 3, 6], [18, 27, 38], [11, 2, 27]]
```

Using `map()`:

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [4, 1, 6]]
[list(map(lambda x : x**2 - 2*x + 3, row)) for row in mat]
>> [[2, 3, 6], [18, 27, 38], [11, 2, 27]]
```

If you really want to use a while-loop you could use this very unpythonic approach:

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [4, 1, 6]]
res = []
i = 0
while i < len(mat):
    res.append(list(map(lambda x : x**2 - 2*x + 3, mat[i])))
    i += 1
res
>> [[2, 3, 6], [18, 27, 38], [11, 2, 27]]
```